# ScrollView issue with layout in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, scrollview

ok I have an issue with the layout portion of my ScrollView. I am trying to get he balance of my image view which is a button. The scroll view works fine. However i cannot figure out why my image view keeps changing positions. I first found the issue on report from a user when they downloaded my app off google play. When adding an image or link to the note its jumbled and overlapped.

So i added a scrollview to the layout, however my image view button the line which you will see in the photos, is not at the bottom like it should be. That is not the main issue. The main issue is when an image is added the button to access the menu from the bottom is pushed off almost completely off the screen.

I have adjusted all my elements and the heights and as well as the constraints. I am at a loss of how to fix this issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:isScrollContainer="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/notelay"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainConstraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgDone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etNoteTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:hint="@string/notes_title"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
            android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgBack"
            tools:ignore="Autofill" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDateTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:paddingEnd="13dp"
            android:textColor="@color/ColorGray"
            android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etNoteTitle" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/l1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvDateTime">


            <View
                android:id="@+id/colorView"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@color/ColorBlue" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etNoteSubTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:hint="@string/notes_sub_title"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
                android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/l1">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgNote"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_300sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutWebUrl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutImage">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etWebLink"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="@string/web_url"
                    android:importantForAutofill="no"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgUrlDelete"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_cancel_24"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:text="@string/cancel"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnOk"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:text="@string/ok"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvWebLink"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/ColorGray"
            android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutWebUrl" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etNoteDesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/notes_desc"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
            android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvWebLink" />



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgMore"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/img_bar"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is the image in designer view

[image]

here is the same on an actual device

[image]

here is the image after something is done

[image]

if you notice the `bar` which is the imageview completely goes off screen once you add an image. I can scroll the entire page, just that bar does not scroll up or stays in the same spot after an image is added. My question is, am i using the scrollview correctly? Any advice would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after some testing I figured out what I needed to do. Instead of having the scrollview at the top in the code before in the Main section, i moved the scrollview outside the MainActivity section as the code shows below, then i sectioned off the image view to its own constraint outside the scroll view. It works like a charm now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/notelay"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainConstraint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBack"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgDone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_tick"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:tint="@color/ColorWhite"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etNoteTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:hint="@string/notes_title"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
                android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgBack"
                tools:ignore="Autofill" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDateTime"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:paddingEnd="13dp"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorGray"
                android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etNoteTitle" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvDateTime">


                <View
                    android:id="@+id/colorView"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:background="@color/ColorBlue" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etNoteSubTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:hint="@string/notes_sub_title"
                    android:importantForAutofill="no"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/l1">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgNote"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_300sdp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgDelete"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutWebUrl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutImage">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etWebLink"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:hint="@string/web_url"
                        android:importantForAutofill="no"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgUrlDelete"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_cancel_24"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:text="@string/cancel"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnOk"
                        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:text="@string/ok"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvWebLink"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorGray"
                android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/layoutWebUrl" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etNoteDesc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:autofillHints=""
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="@string/notes_desc"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/ColorWhite"
                android:textColorHint="@color/ColorGray"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvWebLink" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMore"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_48sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/img_bar"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```